# location of .db file in different android phones

Tags: android, database

when we use sqlLite database for our projects does the path of .db file **/data/data/com.yourpackage.name/databases.** remains the same for each and every android phone??
or path of storage of .db file differ in android phones?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not matter. You find out the path for your app's database [via `getDatabasePath()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath%28java.lang.String%29), which will resolve to the correct spot for the particular device.

Comment: can u provide with small example how to implement getDatabasePath();

Comment: @user1441732: It is a method. You call it on your `Activity`. You do not "implement" it.